# NX faster when connecting from Ubuntu than Windows?

Tags: nx

I have an NX server on my machine at home.  If I connect to it from my Ubuntu laptop it is very fast and usable.  However, if I connect to it from my Win 7 machine it is much slower and difficult to use.  Is this normal?  I tried changing the settings on the Windows client, but can't get it to match the performance of the Ubuntu client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off Direct Draw under the Advanced tab in the Windows client seemed to more or less solve the problem.

http://www.nomachine.com/ar/view.php?ar_id=AR02G00527